# Idris - define interface dynamically

Tags: interface, record, idris

Is there a way to build the implementation of an interface "dynamically"?
I have some code which looks like

```
record MySemigroup where
  constructor MkMySemigroup
  set : Type
  op  : set -> set -> set
  
mySemigroupIsSemigroup : (s : MySemigroup) -> Semigroup (set s)
mySemigroupIsSemigroup s = ?hole
```

and I would like to define the instance of `Semigroup` on `set s` using `op s`.